# Install a specific version of spyder through conda

Tags: python, conda, spyder, miniconda

I have installed miniconda on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine. I want to install `Spyder 5.0.2` through conda. I do not want v5.0.0 as it's icons are messed up.

`conda install spyder=5`  dosent install v5.0.2

`conda install spyder=5.0.2` gives `PackageNotFoundError`

I have also tried `conda update conda`, `conda install spyder=5.0.2` but it gives the same error.

Miniconda has --

```
conda 4.10.1
python 3.8.3
```

Answer (score 2):

Write it like this:

```
conda install spyder-app=5.0.2
```

You might also want to install anaconda navigator, go to anaconda prompt and type:

```
conda install anaconda-navigator
```

Open navigator and navigate to spyder and install the version you want.
Here is the screenshot [image: Anaconda Navigator]

Comment: this did not work, same `PackagesNotFoundError`

Comment: Run the anaconda prompt as admin and then just type conda install spyder=5.0.2

Comment: how do you run anaconda prompt as administrator in Ubuntu?

Comment: Admin equivalent in Ubuntu should be root user, you can access it by using 'sudo' command, but instead of that, have you installed anaconda navigator? if no, you should, it just has a settings button where you can install any specific version, attaching a photo ASAP.

Comment: I think if it is possible through navigator then it should be possible through terminal. Anyways, not always it shows you all the version updates.

Comment: Ofcourse it should be, but I'm unable to figure out why you can't, if navigator is something you don't want to install. you can always clone the github repo of any version you want [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases)

Answer (score 2):

## Try Conda Forge Channel

If the configuration is a **base** Miniconda install, then you likely only have the **defaults** channel. Conda Forge's channel tends to release earlier, so try installing from there, e.g.,

```bash
conda install conda-forge::spyder[version='>=5.0.2']
```

---

### Note on Spyder Kernels

Please be aware that the recommended workflow for Spyder with Conda is to have a single dedicated environment for Spyder, and install the `spyder-kernels` package in environments that you wish to use in Spyder. See [the Spyder Documentation](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder). Something like,

```bash
# spyder env
conda create -n spyder -c conda-forge spyder

# kernel env
conda create -n foo -c conda-forge python=3.9 spyder-kernels

# always launch Spyder with
conda activate spyder
spyder

# then switch kernels from within Spyder
```

### Note on Conda Forge

You may want to consider using Conda Forge as your primary source of packages, since it follows releases on PyPI with less lag. See [the Conda Forge documentation](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/introduction.html#how-can-i-install-packages-from-conda-forge).

Answer (score 1):

First, uninstall spyder on anaconda. Then run cmd prompt (for windows) and use this command.

```
conda install -c conda-forge spyder=5.3.1
```