# Spyder can not connect to kernel when starting in a new conda enviroment

Tags: conda, spyder, python-3.10

I run the following commands:

1. conda create --name py310
2. conda activate py310
3. conda install pip
4. pip install spyder

Afterwards I end up with the following setup:

```
conda list
# packages in environment at c:\programs\Anaconda3\envs\py310:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
alabaster                 0.7.12                   pypi_0    pypi
arrow                     1.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
astroid                   2.11.5                   pypi_0    pypi
atomicwrites              1.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     21.4.0                   pypi_0    pypi
autopep8                  1.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
babel                     2.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
backcall                  0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
bcrypt                    3.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
beautifulsoup4            4.11.1                   pypi_0    pypi
binaryornot               0.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
black                     22.3.0                   pypi_0    pypi
bleach                    5.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
bzip2                     1.0.8                h8ffe710_4    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2022.5.18.1          h5b45459_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2022.5.18.1              pypi_0    pypi
cffi                      1.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
chardet                   4.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
charset-normalizer        2.0.12                   pypi_0    pypi
click                     8.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
cloudpickle               2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
cookiecutter              2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
cryptography              37.0.2                   pypi_0    pypi
debugpy                   1.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
decorator                 5.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
defusedxml                0.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
diff-match-patch          20200713                 pypi_0    pypi
dill                      0.3.5.1                  pypi_0    pypi
docutils                  0.18.1                   pypi_0    pypi
entrypoints               0.4                      pypi_0    pypi
fastjsonschema            2.15.3                   pypi_0    pypi
flake8                    4.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
idna                      3.3                      pypi_0    pypi
imagesize                 1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        4.11.4                   pypi_0    pypi
inflection                0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
intervaltree              3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ipykernel                 6.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
ipython                   7.34.0                   pypi_0    pypi
ipython-genutils          0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
isort                     5.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
jedi                      0.18.1                   pypi_0    pypi
jellyfish                 0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jinja2                    3.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jinja2-time               0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema                4.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-client            7.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-core              4.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-pygments       0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
keyring                   23.5.1                   pypi_0    pypi
lazy-object-proxy         1.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
libffi                    3.4.2                h8ffe710_5    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.12               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib-inline         0.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
mccabe                    0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   0.8.4                    pypi_0    pypi
mypy-extensions           0.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
nbclient                  0.6.4                    pypi_0    pypi
nbconvert                 6.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
nbformat                  5.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
nest-asyncio              1.5.5                    pypi_0    pypi
numpydoc                  1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   3.0.3                h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
packaging                 21.3                     pypi_0    pypi
pandocfilters             1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
paramiko                  2.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
parso                     0.8.3                    pypi_0    pypi
pathspec                  0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pexpect                   4.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pickleshare               0.7.5                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       22.1.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
platformdirs              2.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pluggy                    1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
prompt-toolkit            3.0.29                   pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
ptyprocess                0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pycodestyle               2.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.21                     pypi_0    pypi
pydocstyle                6.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyflakes                  2.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pylint                    2.14.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pyls-spyder               0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pynacl                    1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 3.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5                     5.15.6                   pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5-qt5                 5.15.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5-sip                 12.10.1                  pypi_0    pypi
pyqtwebengine             5.15.5                   pypi_0    pypi
pyqtwebengine-qt5         5.15.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pyrsistent                0.18.1                   pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.10.4          hcf16a7b_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
python-lsp-black          1.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
python-lsp-jsonrpc        1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
python-lsp-server         1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
python-slugify            6.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
python_abi                3.10                    2_cp310    conda-forge
pytz                      2022.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pywin32                   304                      pypi_0    pypi
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    6.0                      pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     23.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
qdarkstyle                3.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
qstylizer                 0.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
qtawesome                 1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
qtconsole                 5.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
qtpy                      2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.27.1                   pypi_0    pypi
rope                      1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
rtree                     1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                62.3.2          py310h5588dad_0    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
snowballstemmer           2.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
sortedcontainers          2.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
soupsieve                 2.3.2.post1              pypi_0    pypi
sphinx                    5.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5                    pypi_0    pypi
spyder                    5.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
spyder-kernels            2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.38.5               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
text-unidecode            1.3                      pypi_0    pypi
textdistance              4.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
three-merge               0.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tinycss2                  1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.12               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
toml                      0.10.2                   pypi_0    pypi
tomli                     2.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tomlkit                   0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tornado                   6.1                      pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 5.2.2.post1              pypi_0    pypi
tzdata                    2022a                h191b570_0    conda-forge
ucrt                      10.0.20348.0         h57928b3_0    conda-forge
ujson                     5.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   1.26.9                   pypi_0    pypi
vc                        14.2                 hb210afc_6    conda-forge
vs2015_runtime            14.29.30037          h902a5da_6    conda-forge
watchdog                  2.1.8                    pypi_0    pypi
wcwidth                   0.2.5                    pypi_0    pypi
webencodings              0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wrapt                     1.14.1                   pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.2.5                h62dcd97_1    conda-forge
yapf                      0.32.0                   pypi_0    pypi
zipp                      3.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
```

In that environment I can type "spyder" and run spyder program; however it never connects to a kernel, while showing spinning wheel and displaying "connecting to kernel..." message. No error messages are displayed.

I had same issue while creating conda environments using python 3.9 and 3.8, using similar sequence of commands. In those environments I did see errors. For example in python 3.8 enviroment I would get

```
(py38) C:\Users\tuszynskij>spyder
fromIccProfile: failed minimal tag size sanity
ERROR:tornado.general:Uncaught exception in ZMQStream callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programs\Anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 556, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\programs\Anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\threaded.py", line 117, in _handle_recv
    ident, smsg = self.session.feed_identities(msg_list)
  File "c:\programs\Anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\session.py", line 968, in feed_identities
    idx = msg_list.index(DELIM)
AttributeError: '_asyncio.Future' object has no attribute 'index'
......
```

With several more pages of "AttributeError: '_asyncio.Future' object has no attribute 'index'" errors.

Spyder works fine in the base enviroment.

Comment: Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67866511/570918

Comment: I think this is related with jupyter_client=>7.3.2. You can check the issue following that here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/18174

Comment: I was having the same issue and @DanielAlthviz's comment was exactly what I needed. It might help you too.